# OpenSubtitles API - SearchSubtitles returns no data

Tags: javascript, api, xml-rpc

I am following this [tutorial](http://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/XMLRPC#SearchSubtitles) to make API calls to OpenSubtitles. I am using Javascript, and [mimic.js](http://mimic-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/) as XML-RPC client. Why is the following code not working?

```
var loginRequest= new XmlRpcRequest("http://api.opensubtitles.org/xml-rpc", "LogIn");
loginRequest.params = (['', '', 'eng', 'OS Test User Agent']);
var response1= loginRequest.send();
var token=String(response1.parseXML().token);
console.log(token);

var searchRequest = new XmlRpcRequest("http://api.opensubtitles.org/xml-rpc", "SearchSubtitles");
searchRequest.params= [token, [['query= South Park', 'season= 1', 'episode=1']]];
var results = searchRequest.send();
console.log(results.parseXML());
```

In return I get no data (data:false). The token part is working fine.

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue. Turns out that mimic.js requires to pass the key value pair in an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for the search is added below in case somebody needs it. Note that query is passed in an object to addParam:

```
var searchRequest = new XmlRpcRequest("http://api.opensubtitles.org/xml-rpc", "SearchSubtitles");
searchRequest.addParam(token);
searchRequest.addParam([{query: 'South Park'}]);
var results = searchRequest.send();
console.log(results.parseXML());
```